# PHP - Parse file to executable and get returned file

Tags: php, executable

I was curious on how I would parse a file in PHP as an executable argument and then get the returned file.

I need to do this, but I'm sure sure whether I use system or exec.

```
    User Uploads File
>
    File is sanitized?
>
    File is parsed to an executable with arguments
>
    File is returned from the executable
>
    User downloads file
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Sorry that I wasn't clear enough. What is happening is the user uploads any file, and then this file is parsed to another executable with some arguments on what the executable is then to do with the file. Once it's done that, it returns a file which PHP then needs to be able to retrieve so the user can download it.

If I start a batch file that parses String arguments to the file, it only returns what's within the batch file, not what the program is returning - so I know that it is communicating with the file correctly.

Comment: please clarify more about the process

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate on what you want to achieve. 
You want to pass a valid PHP file as an argument, execute the PHP and give back a resulting html page?

Is that what you are saying? From where would the "argument" file come? Is it on the server? If so, it can be executed. If any file can be uploaded for execution, you would still need to store it on the server prior to execution - how would you want to make this secure so that it can't be misused? It would be an open door for any nasty script.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear enough.

What is happening is the user uploads any file, and then this file is parsed to another executable with some arguments on what the executable is then to do with the file. Once it's done that, it returns a file which PHP then needs to be able to retrieve so the user can download it.